# Backtracking Algorithm in Java. What am I missing?

Tags: java

I'm working on a sudoku solver in java that uses recursive backtracking. I'm not sure if I'm missing something or completely not understanding it.

```
public static boolean solveHelper(int[][] puzzle) {
    int filled = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < puzzle.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < puzzle.length; j++) {
            if (puzzle[i][j] != 0) {
                filled++;
            }
        }
    }
    if (filled == 81) {

        return true;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            if (puzzle[i][j] == 0) {
                for (int k = 1; k <= 9; k++) {
                    puzzle[i][j] = k;
                    if (valid(puzzle, i, j)) {
                        if (solveHelper(puzzle)) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    } else {
                        puzzle[i][j] = 0;
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

My understanding is that when `return false;` is executed the program will continue to the next time the `sovleHelper()` method is called until `solveHelper()` returns true. Instead the method always returns false. I would like some help understanding how backtracking is supposed to work here.

Here is what is the 2d array before it is passed through `solveHeleper()`

```
 2  0  0  |  0  0  0  |  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  |  0  0  0  |  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  |  0  0  0  |  0  0  0 
----------------------------------

 0  0  0  |  3  0  0  |  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  |  0  0  0  |  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  |  0  0  0  |  0  0  0 
----------------------------------

 0  0  0  |  0  0  0  |  0  0  0 
 0  0  0  |  0  0  0  |  0  4  0 
 0  0  0  |  0  0  0  |  0  0  7
```

And this is is what is the 2d array after it is passed through `solveHelper()`

```
 2  1  3  |  4  5  6  |  7  8  9 
 4  5  6  |  1  2  3  |  0  0  0 
 7  8  9  |  0  0  0  |  1  2  3 
----------------------------------

 1  2  4  |  3  6  5  |  8  7  0 
 3  6  5  |  2  1  4  |  9  0  0 
 8  7  0  |  9  0  0  |  2  1  4 
----------------------------------

 5  3  1  |  6  4  2  |  0  9  8 
 6  9  2  |  5  3  1  |  0  4  0 
 0  4  8  |  0  9  0  |  3  5  7
```

`solveHelper()` should only return true if if none of the values in `puzzle[][]` are 0.

Comment: where is `valid()`

Answer (score 0):

Check the statement `puzzle[i][j] = k;`.
If I understood well, you fill a cell with a value between 1 and 9. If that value is not valid (I suppose your `valid()` function checks the well known sudoku rules), you reset the value of the cell and return `false`.
This means that the whole function returns `false` as soon as you attempt to fill a cell with a non-valid value.

Comment: Yes you understand correctly. But the problem (I think) is when the function returns `false` it exists the loop and function. What I want to happen is for the function to go back to the beginning of the loop when the value is not valid or = 0. I'll update the question with the values that result in `puzzle[][]`

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
                } else {
                    puzzle[i][j] = 0;
                    return false;
                }
```

to

```
                } else {
                    continue;
                }
```

because you need to continue your `k` loop, not start over.